# Distributing a Python Command Line Program with Multiple Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to release a command line program written in Python to the public, but would first like to test it to make sure that the program works as I intend. To do so, I create a simple `wheel` distribution of the program, create a `virtualenv` instance in another directory, and install the `wheel` into said environment. Easy, right?

Not so.

When I attempt to call the program in the testing environment, I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/testing/bin/leprechaun", line 7, in <module>
    from leprechaun.main import main
  File "~/testing/lib/python3.4/site-packages/leprechaun/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import generator
ImportError: No module named 'generator'
```

So, it seems that the `generator.py` file isn't being imported for some reason. What's strange, however, is that `generator.py` and `main.py` (the main entry point to the program) exist in the same directory.

For reference, here's my project's tree hierarchy:

```
├── leprechaun
│   ├── data
│   │   └── A bunch of text files that aren't important
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── generator.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── rainbow.py
├── LICENSE.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

And, for kicks, my `setup.py` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = re.search("^__version__\s*=\s*\"(.*)\"$",
  open("leprechaun/__init__.py").read(), re.M).group(1)

setup(
  name='leprechaun',
  version=version,
  description="A simple rainbow table generator",
  long_description=open("README.rst", encoding="utf-8").read(),
  author="My Name",
  author_email="My Email",
  url="https://github.com/zcdziura/leprechaun",
  license="MIT",
  packages=find_packages(),
  package_data={
    "leprechaun": ["data/wordlist*"]
  },
  entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
      "leprechaun = leprechaun.main:main"
    ]
  }
)
```

I assumed that the entry-point script that is generated would simply call the `main` function from my package, which would then be able to import modules from the same directory. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing deals with absolute imports. You might want to take a look at [this PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more information on what the rationale behind it is.

The short answer is that every import statement you make now looks along `sys.path`. Whereas in Python 2.x, you could use `import generator` and it would look in the current directory, Python 3.x requires it to be along the path. So if you change to `from leprechaun import generator` or `from . import generator` you should be able to clear this up.

Comment: That did it! I didn't realize that Python 3 changed the import behavior. I guess it makes sense why they did it, though. Now I simply have to fix a couple of new bugs that have sprung up. Thank you!